# Local statistical model for percolation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model, lattice-model, percolation

I am interested in classical statistical models with degrees of freedom with a finite configuration set on regular lattices, and Boltzmann weights depending on the configurations in a constant-size region. Examples are the Ising model, Potts model, or hard-hexagon model.

**Question: How do I formulate percolation (in 2 dimensions) as such a classical statistical model?**

Let's consider bond percolation on a 2-dimensional square lattice. By the definitions on Wikipedia and other introductory sources, we draw for each edge of the lattice independently whether it is 'open' with probability $p$ or 'closed' with probability $1-p$. The central quantity of interest is then the probability of two sites/vertices belonging to the same cluster. This is not a 2-point function in a local statistical model of the form above, at least not directly.

My first naive attempt to write this as a local model would be to label each cluster by either $0$ or $1$ such that neighboring clusters have different labels. This corresponds to a classical statistical model with a spin ($0$ or $1$) on each lattice vertex, and a Boltzmann weight on each edge of $\frac{1-p}{2}$ if the adjacent spins are different and $p+\frac{1-p}{2}$ if they are equal. But then 1) the correlations between the spins do not measure whether they belong to the same cluster, but only whether they are separated by an even or odd number of cluster domain walls, and 2) this is just the Ising model, which is supposed to be in a different universality class from percolation (talking about the corresponding phase transitions).

As a bonus, I have a similar question about *directed* percolation: How does one write square-lattice 1+1D directed percolation as a brick-layer circuit of classical stochastic maps?
[Edit: I now understand the bonus question; we simply color a vertex $1$ if at least one of its diagonally preceding vertices is colored $1$ and connected by an open bond, and $0$ otherwise. But this strategy cannot be applied to the undirected percolation case where there is no causal order.]

Comment: IIRC the partition function of percolation corresponds to that of the Potts model for $q=1$. Does this help?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks! But I'm very confused, by $q$ do you mean the number of local configurations as usual? Then $q=1$ is trivial, and doesn't even have degrees of freedom, no?

Comment: Similarly, I read that percolation corresponds to $q=1$ of the random cluster model (which I believe one can write as a local statistical model with degrees of freedom on the edges and Boltzmann weights on the vertices, edges, and plaquettes. But again, for $q=1$, the state is just a tensor product of probability distributions of individual edge degrees of freedom, and thus trivial.

Comment: The mapping is between the partition functions, not the model. IIRC you have to use the Fortuin-Kasteleyn expansion of the partition function, which has q as a parameter. Then, non-integer parameters, or q=1, are also allowed. -- See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_cluster_model

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Hmm, I'm still confused: Both the Potts model for $q=1$ and the random cluster model for $q=1$ have partition function $Z=1$ (unsurprisingly since the models themselves are trivial). And I'm having trouble finding the partition function for percolation itself; that's why I'm asking the question. Also, the universality class is a property of a model and not of the number $Z$ (to be fair, the scaling of $Z$ with the system size does give us the central charge which actually tells us quite a lot about the CFT), so I am looking for a concrete model and not just $Z$.